# instantiation of an object which its type is passed as an argument

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, mvp

I have an event in which I have to instantiate a Form :

```
   Private Sub ParametresEtablissement(ByRef frmmain As Form, ByRef frmparametablissement As Form, ByRef OpenedForms As FormCollection, ByVal TypeOfFrmEtablissement As Type)
            If (frmparametablissement Is Nothing) Then
                frmparametablissement = New TypeOfFrmEtablissement
                frmparametablissement.MdiParent = frmmain
                frmparametablissement.Show()
            Else
End Sub
```

But I have an error in this line :

```
 frmparametablissement = New TypeOfFrmEtablissement
```

the error is `Type TypeOfFrmEtablissement is not defined`

So I need to know:

1. What are the reasons of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `TypeOfFrmEtablissement`? Does it have a default constructor?

You might want to look at [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx). You can pass in an object type as a parameter and it will return an instance using the default constructor of that type.

```
Dim instance As IExample = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(theType), IExample)
```

You could also look at [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) for creating objects but I think that would be overkill for your requirements.

```
Public Function f(Of T)() As T
    Dim tmp As T = GetType(T).GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
    Return tmp
End Function
```

*Update follow Lamloumi's comment* :

I created a new project added a new form (Form2) and called this from the Form1 constructor and a new instance of Form2 was created and displayed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim frmparametablissement As Form = CreateFormInstance(Form2)
    frmparametablissement.Show()
End Sub

Private Function CreateFormInstance(Of T As Form)(type As T) As T
    Return Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T))
End Function
```

Comment: In my case , the type is passed as an argument : TypeOfFrmEtablissement is a windows form